# Json Schema Not working for nested Attributes

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to add some validation to my json schema . I am validating json schema against json using this website https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/. I am not able to put validation on eventPayload/totalAmount based on value present in eventName. It is not failing when it should fail. Should I give the whole path of eventName attribute as it is not present in eventPayload ? If yes, how to do[image] that.

```
    "totalAmount": {
      "type": [
        "integer",
        "number"
      ],
      "minLength": 1,
      "multipleOf": 0.01,
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "eventName": {
            "enum": [
              "Test10",
              "Test12"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "totalAmount": {
            "exclusiveMinimum": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "else": {
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "eventName": {
              "enum": [
                "Test1",
                "Test2",
                "Test3"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {
            "totalAmount": {
              "exclusiveMaximum": 0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to reference values up the tree (e.g. `totalAmount` is below `eventName`), you have to define from the top down. Using `oneOf` (instead of `if/then/else`) and schema composition, you could solve it as follows (minimal example):

Schema:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "eventName": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["Test10", "Test12", "Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]
        },
        "eventPayload": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "totalAmount": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "eventName": {
                    "enum": ["Test10", "Test12"]
                },
                "eventPayload": {
                    "properties": {
                        "totalAmount": {
                            "exclusiveMinimum": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "eventName": {
                    "enum": ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]
                },
                "eventPayload": {
                    "properties": {
                        "totalAmount": {
                            "exclusiveMaximum": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here, we first define the general structure in the `properties` object (no validation yet, just the type of expected objects). Then, in the `oneOf` array we add the alternatives: If `eventName` is either "Test10" or "Test12" apply the `exclusiveMinimum`, if it is one of the others, apply `exclusiveMaximum`.

Any incoming json has to fulfill **both** the schema defined in `properties` **and** *one of* the schemas in `oneOf`. This way of layering schemas is how json schema implements composition. Using this schema and https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ we can verify that it

**accepts**

```json
{
    "eventName": "Test12",
    "eventPayload": {
      "totalAmount": 5
    }
}
```

and

```json
{
    "eventName": "Test2",
    "eventPayload": {
      "totalAmount": -5
    }
}
```

but **rejects**

```json
{
    "eventName": "Test12",
    "eventPayload": {
      "totalAmount": -5
    }
}
```

and

```json
{
    "eventName": "Test2",
    "eventPayload": {
      "totalAmount": 5
    }
}
```

Comment: I am facing one issue . It is validating the amounts properly but also giving one extra error that the value is not present in enum , although it is there and it is validating the same.

Comment: Message:
Float -20.21 is less than minimum value of 0.
Schema path:
#/oneOf/0/properties/eventPayload/properties/totalAmount/minimum
Message:
Value "Test1" is not defined in enum.
Schema path:
#/oneOf/1/properties/eventName/enum

Comment: Also in case amount passed is correct then that extra error of value not present in enum is not coming.

Comment: This is caused by the validator not being able to "guess" which of the two `oneOf` schemas is the intended one. Instead, you get the validation errors for both: for one the amount is wrong, for the other the value of the enum.

Answer (score 0):

The `properties` keyword in your `if` clause will evaluate to true if property eventName is not present. To ensure that it is, add `"required": ["eventName"]` to the condition.

Comment: I already have required on eventName. Check the screenshot.